# Find kernel and image in $p : -\frac{x}{2} = y = z$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Linear projection $A :  \mathbb{R}_3 \to \mathbb{R}_3$   given as the perpendicular projection on the line $p$
$$p : -\frac{x}{2} = y = z$$

How can i find the kernel and image of projection $A$?

i try this:

$t=(2,-1,-1)$

$Im = (0,0,0) +a (2, -1, -1); a\in \mathbb{R}$

$Ker <(2,-1,-1), (x,y,z)> = 0$

$2x -y-z = 0$

$Ker = lin \{ [x y z]^T, 2x -y -z = 0\}$

Comment: If you mean projection to the line p, then the kernel consists of those points which lie in that plane through the origin which has   p normal to it (the line from any point in that plane to the origin is perpendicular to the given line p). So what is the dimension of the kernel? What about the image? What must the image be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do algebra, the definition of the projection tells you everything.

Projection on line $p$ obviously maps the entire space to this line. The *image* of the projection is the line itself. The *kernel* are all the points that have zero projection to this line: a plane, perpendicular to this line.

This also means that the *cokernel* is equal to the *image* (points on the line stay there), and vice-versa.